# Citus "create_distributed_table" giving "PG::UndefinedColumn"

Tags: activerecord, citus, acts-as-tenant

When trying to create a distributed table with Citus, it gives a `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "x" does not exist`

I have enabled Citus on workers and main DB:

```
SELECT run_command_on_workers($cmd$
  CREATE EXTENSION citus;
$cmd$);
```

I created a composite primary key:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
  ALTER TABLE x DROP CONSTRAINT x_pkey CASCADE;
")
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
  ALTER TABLE x ADD PRIMARY KEY (tenant_id, id);
")
```

When trying to do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
SELECT create_distributed_table(x, tenant_id);
")
```

It keeps saying:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "x" does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT create_distributed_table(x, tenant_id...
                                        ^
Caused by PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "x" does not exist
```

Is there something I am forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table name and column name need to be passed as text values in single quotes: SELECT create_distributed_table('x', 'tenant_id');